# Como acceder a un array en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo un array que se forma desde una consulta firebase, lo que sucede es que no he podido acceder a los datos del arreglo que se muestra de la siguiente forma en consola:

```
0: {id: 'bEMJ1vovH3uya79Tevcd', color: 'azul', local: '1'}
1: {id: 'cHze8ZBh2JwGLAyTePBG', color: 'azul', local: '1'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Esta es la instrucción, que muestra en consola:

```
data = data.sort((a, b) => a.orden - b.orden)
 console.log(data)
```

Pero no me deja acceder a los elementos, espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Se trata de un array de objetos, si no entiendo mal tu pregunta loq eu quieres es acceder a los datos almacenados.
Si data es el array puedes acceder por el índice de cada objeto y luego a sus propiedades.

```
    //Si data es el array de datos 
    data = [ {id: 'bEMJ1vovH3uya79Tevcd', color: 'azul', local: '1'}, 
             {id: 'cHze8ZBh2JwGLAyTePBG', color: 'azul', local: '1'}]
    //Puedes acceder con índice y nombre de propiedad
    console.log(data[0].id);
    console.log(data[0].color);
    console.log(data[0].local);
```

Espero haber interpretado bien tu pregunta

Comment: Hola, creo que el problema es que en la consola aparece [[Prototype]]: Array(0) como si no hubiera nada dentro del array y no entiendo porque sucede.